# Configuring SSL inside Spring JDBC template class

Tags: java, spring, datasource

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database which uses SSL for authentication service in the database.  I don't have the DB connectivity details yet I think I need to configure the following in the config file:

```xml
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addConnectionProperty" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType</value>
            <value>JKS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addConnectionProperty" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType</value>
            <value>JKS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I used the following property file **"org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"** inside the Spring Framework class and added the value in the following way

```
// @SpringFramework: what goes here?
```

It's throwing the following error

the above mentioned spring beans needs to be used.

Comment: <property name="addConnectionProperty">
         <props>
          <prop key="oracle.net.authentication_services">TCPS</prop>
          <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType">JKS</prop>
          <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">""</prop>
          <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType">JKS</prop>
          <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStore">""</prop>
  </props>

Comment: this is the piece of code i am using in the config file

Comment: you are still missing something that should have followed _"added the value in the following way"_

Comment: @StephenP i found a way to refer those and i did it in the following way, 

<bean
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
  lazy-init="false">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="addConnectionProperty" />
  <property name="arguments">
   <list>
    <value>javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType</value>
    <value>JKS</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>


dataSource is refered by BasicDataSource

Comment: As i don't have the connectivity details yet, i believe this should work fine. Will keep you guys posted.

Comment: SpringFramework - are you able to edit your question and put that in the right place there, instead of putting it in a comment?

Comment: @Stephen - Edited with the piece of the code. 
As i don't have the DB connection details yet i don't think if this piece of code will work and i can establish a connection to DB but i highly think otherwise.